# "efi" partitioning when installing ubuntu 18.04 on a system with pre-installed window

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, android-source, ubuntu-18.04

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04 for AOSP learning. I have a system with a pre-installed window and UEFI. I have already selected the "Something else" option on installation. Now I am partitioning as follows:

Before installation started:

```
     Device     Type    Size       Used         System

1. /dev/sda1    efi    272MB       44MB      Windows Boot Manager
2. /dev/sda2           16MB       unknown
3. /dev/sda3    ntfs  107374MB    unknown
4. /dev/sda4    ntfs  107374MB    unknown
5. /dev/sda5    ntfs   1048MB     unknown
freespace ...
```

According to my understanding, the free space (which is 1TB - Allocated Memory to the window) should be divided as:

```
1. ext4  /         32768 MB
2. ext4  /boot     1024 MB
3. ext4  /var      6143 MB
4. efi             500 MB
5. swap            32768 MB  (which 2 * 16GB RAM)
6. ext4  /home     remaining memory
```

I have a doubt on the 4th partitioning because window already has this partition of size 272 MB. Please guide to proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, there is no need of specific efi partition for ubuntu but instead, install the Ubuntu on efi partition where a window is installed. So the final table of the partition will be:

1. ext4  /         32768 MB
2. ext4  /boot     1024 MB
3. ext4  /var      6143 MB
4. swap            32768 MB  (which 2 * 16GB RAM)
5. ext4  /home     remaining memory

Device bootloader location selection should be:
/dev/sda1    efi